# Using Selenium to extract web elements not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape Google Maps using Beautiful soup and Selenium. My initial goal is to navigate to the first result of my search and extract the Address and URL. I've succeeded in searching and navigating to the first result of my search. However I can't seem to extract the other elements. This is an example of the address element 2620 Someplace Dr, anywhere, NY 12567

I've tried Xpath and Class methods i.e. `address_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[9]/div[3]/button/div/div[2]/div[1]')`

Do y'all have any thoughts or suggestions on extracting this element?

Edit:
Web element with address removed
`<div class="Io6YTe fontBodyMedium kR99db ">some address/div>`

Error:
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[9]/div[3]/button/div/div[2]/div[1]"}
(Session info: chrome=116.0.5845.96); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:

Comment: We can't answer your question, because you haven't shown us what the actual results were from that statement, and you also have not shown us the actual html to confirm whether that element was or was not present.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry forgot to inline the element I copied.